# Qual o meio mais apropriado para se concatenar strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string, stringbuilder, concatenação-de-string

Existem diferentes métodos para concatenar strings, como

- Concatenando com o operador `"abc" + str`
- Formatando `String.Format("abc{0}", str);`
- Utilizando o StringBuilder `new StringBuilder("abc").Append(str);`
- Utilizando o método Concat de String `String.Concat("abc", str);`

Em que situação eu devo utilizar cada uma? O que pode ser mais eficiente em cada caso?

Comment: De uma olhada neste [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463932/Efficient-String-and-String-Concatenation-Algorith), tem comparação de performance entre as maneiras de se concatenar `string`.

Comment: No C# 6.0 adicionaram uma nova forma de concatenação, por meio do '$'. Exemplo: string str = "mundo";  $"Olá {str}"; Saída: Olá mundo

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Antes de mais nada,  o que é *constante literal*?

Constante literal é a representação de um *valor* de uma *string* no código fonte, exemplo:

```
"isto é uma constante literal"
```

Outro exemplo:

```
var str = "foo";
```

Nesse exemplo *str* é uma *string* e *"foo"* uma *constante literal*.

Em nosso dia-a-dia não precisamos ressaltar essa diferença, mas quando conversamos sobre performance em cima de strings é fundamental diferenciar. Por constantes literais serem valores que estão presentes diretamente no código fonte isso dá ao compilador a oportunidade de otimizar essas operações (como realizar a concatenação em tempo de compilação).

## Operador +

```
"A temperatura em " + cidade + " é de " + temperatura;
```

**Pró**:

- Se concatenada constantes literais a concatenaçao é realizada em tempo de compilação.
- É considerado o padrão.

**Contra**:

- Pouco legível; díficil edição.

## string.Concat

```
string.Concat("A temperatura em ", cidade, " é de ", temperatura);
```

Em termos de performance é idêntico ao operador `+` (exceto em caso de constantes literais).

## string.Format

```
string.Format("A temperatura em {0} é de {1}", cidade, temperatura);
```

**Pró**:

- Preferido por muitos ao formatar a concatenação (mais legível).
- Fácil de utilizar uma string concatenada várias vezes na string original (basta repetir o índice).

**Contra**:

- Pouco *performático*.
- É gerado um erro de execução (e não de compilação) se um número inválido de paramêtros a ser concatenado for passado.
- Em uma string com muitas concatenações, pode não ser muito amigável ter que ficar mantendo os números dos índices de concatenação.

## StringBuilder

```
new StringBuilder("A temperatura em ").Append(cidade).Append(" é de ").Append(temperatura);
```

*StringBuilder* é uma classe específica para construção de strings. A grande diferença dos métodos anteriores é que enquanto o tradicional tipo *System.String* é um objeto imutável, isto é, toda operação cria uma nova string, já o *StringBuilder* é mutável, fazendo com que seja o mais performático em cenários que envolvam muitas operações (leia-se concatenações em loops).

É importante ressaltar que o uso no exemplo acima é um caso em que **não** se deve utilizar *StringBuilder*.

## Considerações

Nós como programadores gostamos muito deste tipo de assunto mas a realidade é que preocupar com performance em concatenações de string triviais é a chamada *micro otimização* (perceba a conotação ruim).

Como regra geral, eu particulamente, sigo:

- Procuro utilizar a concatenação simples, via operador `+`.
- Se por acaso o projeto em que estou trabalhando assume outra maneira, `string.Concat` por exemplo, passo a utilizá-la. **Consistência** é algo importante.
- Quando um número grande de concatenações de constantes literais é feito preze pelo operador `+`. Essa concatenação será feita em tempo de compilação salvando preciosos ciclos de processamento.
- Quando as strings envolvidas são de grande porte, multiplas operações, operações em loop, enfim, quando um trabalho pesado é feito sobre strings utilize o StringBuilder. Não utilize-o para trabalhos triviais.

Comment: O que quer dizer "pouco performático"?

Comment: @FranciscoJunior significa ter *baixa* performance; uma performance ruim.

Comment: Imaginei, embora não conhecesse esse termo. Será que não seria mais claro para o leitor se estivesse escrito "baixo desempenho"?

Answer (score 9):

Como toda string pode ser considerada um Array de caracteres, concatenar strings do modo clássico é muito custoso. Pois  a cada `+` usado, uma cópia de uma nova string é gerada em memória. No caso do C#, como explicado a seguir, concatenações usando `+` são traduzidas para `String.Concat()`.

O melhor modo é usar a classe `StringBuilder` junto com o método `Append`.
Veja como é a implementação de uma classe StringBuilder para entender como ela melhora a performance da concatenação: http://dteixeira.com/847/exploring-arrays-introduction/

**Quando usar:** Concatenações dentro de loops, quando a quantidade de concatenações não é prevista.

O `String.Format()` é adequado apenas para substituição de placeholders, como: `String.Format("Olá {0}, você tem {1} mensagens.", "Beto", 23);`. Por design, este caminho não é recomendado para concatenação, pois faz o uso de Replaces, que é bem custoso para esse propósito.

O `String.Concat()` tem uma performance igual a concatenar com um sinal de +, pois apenas encapsula o operando `+=` por assim dizer.

Pois o seguinte código:

```
string a = "Um";
string b = "dois";
string c = "Tres";
string d = a + b + c;
```

Será interpretado no compilador como:

```
string a = "Um";
string b = "dois";
string c = "Tres";
string d = String.Concat(a, b, c);
```

**Quando usar:** Se você precisar combinar dois arrays ou Listas em uma variável só. Pois você pode estender esse método para outros tipos de inputs.

Caso queira explorar os detalhes da concatenação de strings, há um [artigo detalhado sobre isso](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html).

Comment: Existe um custo para instanciar um StringBuilder que faz com que esta abordagem não seja recomendada (em termos de performance) para concatenar poucas strings.

Comment: Sim, o StringBuilder é bom quando estamos lidando com concatenações dentro de loops. Caso contrário, o uso do Concat é melhor. Vou adicionar essa edição na resposta.

Comment: As opcoes 2 e 3 podem ser combinadas em uma so usando ``StringBuilder.AppendFormat()``

Comment: Não é criada uma nova string por cada `+`. Os `+` são traduzidos pelo compilador em chamadas a `String.Concat` que pode receber vários parâmetros.

Comment: O `String.Format` não usa `Replace`. Usa `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` que também não usa `Replace`.

Comment: Paulo Morgado, estou interessado em saber alguma fonte onde possa ler sobre como o String.Concat funciona internamente?

Comment: @Dorival você pode descompilar a classe `System.String` para ter uma idéia de como seus métodos foram implementados.

Comment: Sim Humberto, só queria saber se alguém tinha algo out of the pocket :)

Answer (score 6):

Na dúvida, teste...

Tempos obtidos com o código abaixo (é um benchmark tosko e varia de acordo com o número de iterações, mas dá pra ter uma idéia):

Testando TestarSoma... 37.076 ms

Testando TestarConcat... 36.346 ms

Testando TestarStringBuilder... 3 ms

Testando TestarStream... 10 ms

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class Program
    {

        private const int LOOP_COUNT = 100000;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Testar(TestarSoma);
            Testar(TestarConcat);
            Testar(TestarStringBuilder);
            Testar(TestarStream);
        }

        private static void Testar(Func<string> metodo)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            Console.Write("Testando {0}... ", metodo.Method.Name);
            sw.Start();
            metodo();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0:N0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        private static string TestarSoma()
        {
            var a = "Um";
            var b = "Dois";
            var c = "Três";
            var d = "";

            for (var ct = 0; ct <= LOOP_COUNT; ct++)
            {
                d += a + b + c;
            }

            return d;
        }

        private static string TestarConcat()
        {
            var a = "Um";
            var b = "Dois";
            var c = "Três";
            var d = "";

            for (var ct = 0; ct <= LOOP_COUNT; ct++)
            {
                d = string.Concat(d, a, b, c);
            }

            return d;
        }

        private static string TestarStringBuilder()
        {
            var a = "Um";
            var b = "Dois";
            var c = "Três";
            var d = new StringBuilder();

            for (var ct = 0; ct <= LOOP_COUNT; ct++)
            {
                d.Append(a);
                d.Append(b);
                d.Append(c);
            }

            return d.ToString();
        }

        private static string TestarStream()
        {
            var a = "Um";
            var b = "Dois";
            var c = "Três";

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
            {
                for (var ct = 0; ct <= LOOP_COUNT; ct++)
                {
                    sw.Write(a);
                    sw.Write(b);
                    sw.Write(c);
                }

                sw.Flush();
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                using (var sr = new StreamReader(ms))
                {
                    return sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sem dúvida, use `concat()` ou `join()` para juntar **pequenos** pedaços de string.

Para concatenar algo como **várias** frases/linhas grandes (não importa se dentro ou fora de loop) considere utilizar `StringBuilder`.

Só use o `+` se for concatenar **LETRAS** ou poucas PALAVRAS.

Veja esta [página](http://webinfocentral.com/tech/ConcatenateStrings.aspx), **teste COM A SUA string** e tire sua conclusão.