# Por que devo usar a classe StringBuilder ao invés da classe String?

Tags: c#, .net, string, stringbuilder

Por que essas duas classes são diferentes, pois me parece que poderiam ser uma classe só.

Por exemplo, o método `Append`, me parece que ele faz a mesma coisa que o operador `+`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basicamente para evitar o problema do [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

[image: Shlemiel the painter's algorithm]

A *string* em C# é [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101). Quando você vai adicionando novas partes na *string*, é necessário fazer uma nova alocação de memória e copiar todo o conteúdo existente para adicionar o novo conteúdo. Claro que existe alguma otimização para não acontecer tanto assim, mas acontece bem mais do que é aceitável na maioria das situações. Imagine que cada vez a alocação é maior e vai gastando mais tempo, tornando seu uso impraticável (inclusive porque vai botando pressão no *garbage collector*).

O tipo [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) é mutável. Então só as partes novas são alocadas e o objeto vai ligando essas partes. Quando há alteração em trechos do texto, ele efetivamente é alterado em vez de criar um novo texto.

É claro que não é em qualquer situação que o `StringBuilder` será claramente mais eficiente. Muitos programadores que já conhecem o problema acham que qualquer concatenação deve usá-lo, isto não é verdade. [Se você souber quantos e quais são os trechos a serem concatenados, é desnecessário usar este tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124/101). Então ele costuma ser mais vantajoso apenas em laços grandes ou potencialmente grandes.

Note que internamente há diferenças e você não pode simplesmente usar o conteúdo de uma `StringBuilder` onde se espera algo do tipo `string`. Uma conversão é necessária. Então em casos de poucas concatenações a vantagem nem é grande.

Algumas das informações passadas são detalhes de implementação, então é possível que cada implementação seja um pouco diferente, de fato já funcionou de um jeito um pouco diferente.

Também fica claro que o objetivo é diferente quando olhamos os métodos de um tipo e o outro. Não temos o mesmo conjunto de comportamentos possíveis. Alguns métodos fazem mais sentido no `StringBuilder` (os principais são `Append`, `Insert`, `Replace` e `Remove`), que não é um tipo adequado para fazer todo tipo de manipulação de *string* que tem bem mais métodos de manipulação básica.

Não vou entrar em muitos detalhes aqui porque há várias respostas sobre o assunto com informações que servem para esta pergunta, mesmo quando fala de outra linguagem.

[Mais detalhes sobre o seu funcionamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16063/101) (é Java mas quase tudo igual).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).