# Qual é a forma aconselhável de montar uma query?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, query, ado.net

Qual é a forma aconselhável de se montar uma *query* no C#? É aconselhável utilizar concatenação com o operador `+`? Por exemplo:

```
query += " WHERE nome LIKE '%" + nome + "%'";
```

Aqui segue uma `query` que montei como exemplo para ilustrar a situação:

```
string query = "SELECT nome, idade FROM Pessoas ";

if (nome != "")
   query += " WHERE nome LIKE '%" + nome + "%'";

query += " ORDER BY idade";
```

Sei que posso utilizar parâmetros também, porem, e se minha *query* conter muitas linhas, é a forma certa usar o operador `+` para quebrar a *query* em varias partes concatenando, tenho algumas dúvidas a respeito.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitivamente não. Pelo menos não desta forma. Está usando o ADO.NET, certo? Então monte a consulta com o componente existente para fazer esta construção. No caso é o [`SQLCommand`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0). Você vai passando os parâmetros por ele. Exemplo:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    var query = "SELECT nome, idade FROM Pessoas ";
    if (nome != "") query += " WHERE nome LIKE '%@Nome%'";
    query += " ORDER BY idade"; //deixei mas poderia otimizar isto
    var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    command.Parameters["@Nome"].Value = nome;
    try {
        connection.Open();
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //só exemplo, deveria fazer algo mais
    }
}
```

Note que montar o texto básico da parte fixa não é um grande problema. Claro que se tiver concatenação demais é melhor usar um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) para [evitar grandes cópias de dados de uma *string* para outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101), já que este tipo é [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) e pode ser muito grande.

```
var query = new StringBuilder("SELECT nome, idade FROM Pessoas ");
if (nome != "") query.Append(" WHERE nome LIKE '%@Nome%'");
query.Append(" ORDER BY idade"); //deixei mas poderia otimizar isto
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/BuildQuery.cs).

O que não pode é concatenar a parte variável, porque aí pode ocorrer o tal do [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101). Precisa deixar a inserção da parte que vem externamente para um método que sabe lidar com este tipo de problema.

Note que você tem que identificar na consulta o que é o parâmetro  e depois enviá-lo, tudo pela classe `SQLCommand`.

Isto pode não resolver todos os problemas de segurança, mas já é um avanço.

Comment: Tenho umas querys  com muitas linhas, ja estou usando o `Parameters` vou usar o `StringBuilder` para concatenar.