# exibir dado de uma coluna do banco mysql em label

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Como dar um select em um dado da minha coluna de uma tabela e mostrá-lo em uma label?

EX:

```
id = 10 -> Banana
Select * From tabela where id = 10
label.Text = Banana


 MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection();
            conexao.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost; user id=root; pwd=root ;database=semi");
            conexao.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
            command.Connection = conexao;
            command.CommandText = "Select Valor_Venda from produtos where    Codigo = '" + comboBox4.Text + "'";
            MySqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            label20.Text = dr;
```

Achei um exemplo na internet e tentei adaptar mais acredito que não estou no caminho correto. Podem me ajudar? Qualquer duvida da minha pergunta comentar que respondo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse seu código, já que você deseja somente um valor retornado, pode fazer diretamente pelo ExecuteScalar.

Ficaria assim (peguei seu código como base):

```
MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection();
conexao.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost; user id=root; pwd=root ;database=semi");
conexao.Open();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
command.Connection = conexao;
command.CommandText = "Select Valor_Venda from produtos where    Codigo = '" + comboBox4.Text + "'";
string valor = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString("C");
label.Text = valor;
```

Comment: Quando for fazer uma consulta no banco que envolve algum tipo de parâmetros é importante usar o [parâmetros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) `@param` pq vai te ajudar e evitar ataques de SQL Injection.

Comment: Eu peguei o código dele e só adicionei algumas coisas, não modifiquei. Eu também prefiro usar parâmetros, mas não sabia que isso evitava ataques dessa maneira, como isso funciona? Você tem um link explicando sobre isso?

Comment: Pode consultar a respeito de SQL Injection [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php). E [aqui tem mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104614/qual-%C3%A9-a-forma-aconselh%C3%A1vel-de-montar-uma-query) a respeito de uso de parâmetros no C#.