# Fazendo o insert no SQL Server em um campo float?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, tipagem, ado.net

Estou com o seguinte problema no meu código, tenho um `textbox` que recebe o valor `0.900`, só que quando estou gravando este valor no banco, esta gravando apenas 900, e preciso que grave o 0.900 e não estou conseguindo gravar desta forma, o campo na tabela do `sql` esta como `float`. Estou tentando fazer desta forma `float.Parse(txt_qtda.Text)` e não esta dando certo, só grava `900` e não `0.900`.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CB0020 (CB0_FILIAL, CB0_CODETI, CB0_DTNASC, CB0_TIPO, CB0_CODPRO, CB0_QTDE, CB0_LOCAL, CB0_LOTE, CB0_DTVLD, CB0_FORNEC, CB0_LOJAFO, CB0_XLOTEF, CB0_XQTDKG, CB0_XORIGE, CB0_XDTFAB, CB0020.R_E_C_N_O_) VALUES ('01','" + txt_codbarras.Text + "', '" + txt_dtnasc.Text + "', '01', '" + txt_codprod.Text + "', '" + float.Parse(txt_qtda.Text) + "', '01', '" + txt_lotefrac.Text + "', '" + Convert.ToDateTime(txt_dtvalidfrac.Text).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Replace("/", "") + "', '" + txt_codfbaric.Text + "', '01', '" + txt_lotefabric.Text + "', '" + float.Parse(txt_qtda.Text) + "', '" + txt_codorig.Text + "', '" + Convert.ToDateTime(txt_dtfabricfrac.Text).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd").Replace("/", "") + "', '" + txt_recno.Text + "')";
cmd.Connection = conex;
conex.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: tem como vc colocar o trecho do codigo que insere no banco de dados?

Comment: coloquei acima o trecho do código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem vários erros aí.

[Isso parece dinheiro ou algo semelhante (quantidade) e `float` nunca deveria ser usado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101) para isto. Isto é um problema seríssimo que causa prejuízos.

[Se houver um digitação errada a aplicação vai quebrar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). O problema na verdade deve estar na conversão ou na entrada do dado.

Se a conversão for correta é para tudo funcionar. Mas se ainda tiver algum motivo para mudar a escala basta dividir por 1000. Não que estou dizendo que é o caso, não vi o todo, mas já vi situação que a solução seria esta. Não use isto como gambiarra, só se for a solução correta. É uma solução útil quando realmente se digita o valor em escala diferente da desejada. Se for para consertar o erro anterior, não faça.

Você tem [sérios problemas de segurança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104614/101) inserindo dados desta forma. Parametrize a *query*.

Estas conversões de data parecem estranhas também.

A nomenclatura das colunas e da tabela costuma ser ruim, mas isso tem um pouco de gosto, ainda que quase todo mundo concordaria que esses nomes são ilegíveis.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, esta tabela e uma tabela de banco de dados da Totvs, todos os campos são criados como varchar, não sei porque isso, mas esta converão não e em valor que estou passando e sim e peso, para impressão de etiquetas somente, então no caso acima seria 0.900kg para impressão de etiquetas, e não valor. me desculpe o código acima não esta mo formato adequado, estou iniciando em c# então acho que ainda tenho muito que aprender...

Comment: Desconfiei, eu trabalhava lá, sempre fui crítico disto. Mas parece que agora está pior que na minha época. Se isto não for usado para mais nada talvez seja só o caso de pedir os dados de outra forma para evitar o erro de digitação. Eu corrigiria o problema de segurança, é muito sério.

Comment: Vou verificar esta parte da segurança sim, muito obrigado pela atenção.