# O que faz o join() ser tão superior se comparado a outras técnicas de concatenação?

Tags: python, desempenho

É comum lermos que o método de concatenação [`join()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) é muito **superior** que outras técnicas no Python (como `+` ou `+=`). Partindo deste ponto, lanço algumas perguntas:

- O que faz o `join()` tão rápido?
- Sempre devo usá-lo ou existem casos em que o `join()` não seria bem vindo?
- Existem métodos mais rápidos que o `join()` para concatenação de strings no Python?

**Referências**

- [PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)
- [ConcatenationTestCode](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConcatenationTestCode)
- [Efficient String Concatenation in Python](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Problema

Existe um problema que um dos criadores desse site (SO) chama de [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Um pintor vai pintando a faixa de ultrapassem de uma rodovia. Ele começa muito bem, com alta produtividade. Mas cada dia ele produz menos, até que depois de algumas iterações seu trabalho fica inviável.

Isso ocorre porque ele mantém a lata de tinta em lugar fixo, então ele pinta uma porção da faixa e tem que voltar ao ponto inicial para molhar o pincel. Cada dia ele está mais afastado da lata e demora mais tempo no trajeto do que na pintura.

[image: Shlemiel the painter's algorithm]

Imagine esse padrão crescendo dezenas, centenas ou milhares de vezes. Rapidamente inviabiliza.

É o que costuma acontecer com concatenações de coleções de dados, especialmente *string*. Conforme ela vai crescendo e não cabe no espaço que existia para a versão anterior, precisa ser feita uma nova alocação para suportar todo o tamanho da nova versão. E tem que desalocar a anterior que virou lixo. E vai fragmentando a memória. Tudo isso é custo de tempo. Em algumas linguagens a situação é pior já que uma alteração que nem estoure o limite de tamanho atual já causa uma realocação (por uma boa causa). É o caso de Python.

## Solução

O jeito correto é descobrir o tamanho final, ou pelo menos uma aproximação disso e alocar tudo o que precisa, pode ir colocando os textos nessa área alocada. Obviamente que precisa ser feito em uma estrutura que aceita o texto ser alterado, o que não é o caso do tipo `string` que é imutável, ou seja, qualquer alteração gera um novo objeto.

O `join()` faz exatamente isso que descrevi. Ele descobre o tamanho total necessário - pegando os tamanhos de todas strings que serão concatenadas - aloca todo espaço necessário e vai jogando os textos nesse espaço que ainda não é uma *string*. No final ele transforma isso em *string*. Aí o custo é equivalente ao tamanho total do texto que é bem mais curto que andar tudo de novo em cada concatenação.

Note que para poucas concatenações, tipicamente até 4, a concatenação pode ter mesmo desempenho ou até melhor que o `join()`. Claro que em volume tão pequeno tanto faz qual é mais rápido.

## Alternativas

É claro que o `join()` não é a única forma de fazer isso. Você pode fazer manualmente se precisa de algo uma pouco mais complexo que o `join()` não atende. Talvez usando um [*bytearray*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) ou uma lista padrão que são mutáveis (ajuda, mas não é ótimo porque pode precisar de novas alocações, ainda que minimizadas, não precisa em cada alteração, depende da habilidade do programador).

A [página do Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips) também mostra como usar `%s` para obter resultado semelhante. A formatação ocorre em uma função que manipula tudo em outra estrutura de dados e só no final que é gerado a *string* final.

Há quem goste de usar o tipo [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/io.html#io.StringIO) que cuida disso.

[Respondi isso em mais detalhes para outras linguagens como Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16063/101). E [também C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 9):

Do artigo: [Efficient String Concatenation](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/)

**Método 1** (concatenação)

```
def method1():
  out_str = ''
  for num in xrange(loop_count):
    out_str += `num`
  return out_str
```

**Método 4** (join)

```
def method4():
  str_list = []
  for num in xrange(loop_count):
    str_list.append(`num`)
  return ''.join(str_list)
```

[image]

O método 4 (join) é significantemente mais rápido que concatenação.

Isso ocorre porque strings são imutáveis, ou seja, elas nem podem ser alteradas. Para "alterar" uma, é necessário criar uma nova representação (uma concatenação das duas) e depois destruir as strings antigas. O join é mais rápido porque o Python é capaz de otimizar esse processo.

O texto [Python: string concatenation VS list join](https://paolobernardi.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/python-string-concatenation-vs-list-join/) também é bem interessante e vai no código fonte da implementação CPython descobrir a resposta:

> Ao usar o método join, o Python aloca memória para a string final apenas uma vez; mas se você concatenar várias strings sucessivamente, o Python tem que alocar nova memória para cada concatenação. Advinha o que é mais rápido? ;)

Ou seja, isso é idêntico em termos de desempenho:

```
final_str = 'abc' + 'def'
final_str = ''.join('abc', 'def')  # não há diferença de desempenho
```

Já se você concatenar mais de duas strings, o join será mais rápido:

```
final_str = 'abc' + 'def' + 'ghi'  # aqui é realizado duas operações sucessivas
final_str = ''.join('abc', 'def', 'ghi')  # aqui é realizado uma só
```