# Encontrar números consecutivos em uma string em C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

Há uma maneira simples de encontrar números consecutivos que sejam iguais em uma *string*, de forma que seja possível substituir essa cadeia por um único valor.

Por exemplo:

```
string input = "Abc111de2234";
string output = "Abc1de234";
```

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Além dessa varredura, existe um jeito mais eficiente de se fazer isso? Por que nesse caso seriam necessários dois 'for', não?

Comment: Por que acha que precisaria de 2 `for`?

Comment: @Maniero Eu tinha pensado em fixar o caractere atual dentro do primeiro for, e caso esse caractere fosse um número, iniciar outro for a partir da posição seguinte para verificar se a condição proposta pelo Diego seria verdadeira. Daria para fazer isso apenas com um for?

Comment: Não consigo imaginar porque isto seria necessário. Quer fazer com todos os caracteres ou só com dígitos?

Comment: @Maniero a substituição que desejo fazer é apenas com os números presentes na string. A questão é que essa string pode ter letras e números juntos. Então a proposta seria identificar somente números, os quais sejam iguais e adjacentes para substituir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível fazer com uma varredura dos caracteres e um só loop, [assim (Exemplo no dotnetfiddle)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XslUOC):

```
string input = "Abc111de2234";
string output = string.Empty; // Desejado: "Abc1de234";
char[] numbers = new []{ '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        if (i > 0)
        {
            if (numbers.Contains(input[i]))
            {
                if(input[i] != input[i-1])
                    output += input[i];
            }
            else
                output += input[i];
        }
        else
            output += input[i];

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Outras formas de fazer incluem o uso de expressões regulares, por exemplo, mas acredito que esta seria menos performática.

Comment: Obrigado, era isso mesmo que estava tentando fazer (só que antes com dois for, sendo algo bem menos eficiente e que estava apresentando problemas na saída). Não tinha pensado em usar um array com os números para auxiliar nas comparações, de fato isso ajuda bastante.

Answer (score 10):

Eu faria assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var texto = "Abcc111de12234";
        var lista = new char[texto.Length];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < texto.Length; i++) if (!char.IsDigit(texto[i]) || (i == 0 || texto[i] != texto[i - 1])) lista[j++] = texto[i];
        WriteLine(new string(lista));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Z0yFMJ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dg7zgg). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/RemoveDuplicateInSequence.cs).

A solução da outra resposta gera várias [alocações e cópias de *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101), tornando a [aplicação lenta e consumindo muita memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153322/101), além de provocar pausas. Tem outras ineficiências. E o código ficou mais limpo, então não tem porque não usar assim.

Comment: Grato pela resposta! Sempre é bom ver um problema sendo resolvido de maneiras diferentes, principalmente para observar a eficiência :)

Comment: Essa resposta deveria ser a aceita