# Lista de objetos gerando string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach

Tenho uma lista de objeto Pessoa que contem uma lista de `Endereços`. Gostaria de imprimir essa pessoa com os endereços em `string`.

```
       var pessoa = new Pessoa() { Nome = "Jão" };

        var e = new Endereco() { Cidade = "São Paulo", Estado = "SP", Pessoa = pessoa };
        var e1 = new Endereco() { Cidade = "Rio de Janeiro", Estado = "RJ", Pessoa = pessoa };
        var e2 = new Endereco() { Cidade = "Belo Horizonte", Estado = "MG", Pessoa = pessoa };

        pessoa.Enderecos.Add(e);
        pessoa.Enderecos.Add(e1);
        pessoa.Enderecos.Add(e2);

        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in pessoa.Enderecos)
        {
            result += item.Cidade + " | " + item.Estado + " | ";
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine($"Endereços: {result}");
```

O meu resultado está correto:

> Endereços: São Paulo | SP | Rio de Janeiro | RJ | Belo Horizonte | MG |

**Gostaria de imprimir os endereços em uma única string utilizando LINQ ao invés de `foreach` com o mesmo resultado de saída que eu obtive, seria possível?**

```
    string result = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in pessoa.Enderecos)
    {
        result += item.Cidade + " | " + item.Estado + " | ";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código melhorado e com a opção do LINQ:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var pessoa = new Pessoa() { Nome = "Jão" };
        pessoa.Enderecos = new List<Endereco> {
            new Endereco() { Cidade = "São Paulo", Estado = "SP", Pessoa = pessoa },
            new Endereco() { Cidade = "Rio de Janeiro", Estado = "RJ", Pessoa = pessoa },
            new Endereco() { Cidade = "Belo Horizonte", Estado = "MG", Pessoa = pessoa }
        };
        var result = new StringBuilder(pessoa.Enderecos.Count * 36); //tamanho máximo de cada cidade
        foreach (var item in pessoa.Enderecos) result.Append(item.Cidade + " | " + item.Estado + " | ");
        WriteLine($"Endereços: {result}");
        result.Clear();
        pessoa.Enderecos.ForEach(item => result.Append(item.Cidade + " | " + item.Estado + " | "));
        WriteLine($"Endereços: {result}");
    }
}

public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome;
    public List<Endereco> Enderecos;
}

public class Endereco {
    public string Cidade;
    public string Estado;
    public Pessoa Pessoa;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5GhGgR). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pVIkNK). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/BuildString.cs).

Seu código está caindo do problema do [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153322/101) e torna o código bastante ineficiente. Em alguns casos pode não ser tão crítico, mas eu não arriscaria sem.

Ainda não arrumei o fato do tipo `Pessoa` deixar [criar o objeto em estado inválido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101), entre outros problemas que não vale colocar aqui, até porque alguns depende um pouco de contexto como [expor detalhes de implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101), ou fazer referência cruzada entre a pessoa e o endereço (tem caso pra uso, mas quase sempre é um erro, mas se precisa garante que está vazando abstração).

E cuidado, gostar e ser o certo são duas coisas diferentes, o LINQ chama-se Language INtegrated **Query**. Ou seja, ela é feita para consultas e não para processamentos. Esse caso até faz sentido, mas muita gente começa usar o `ForEach()` para processamento e está errado, ainda que funcione.