# Como corrigir erro Time limit exceeded

Tags: python, lógica, uri

Estava tentando resolver esta questão no URI e consegui chegar à saída exigida pelo URI. Porém obtive o erro `Time limit exceeded`, pois o tempo limite de execução é 2s, e meu código resultou em 3s. Gostaria que me ajudassem a otimizar meu código para não exceder este limite.

Link da questão no URI e imagem do enunciado:

https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1146

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```py
N = 1
sequencia = ''
while N != 0:

    N = int(input())
    i = 1

    while i <= N:
        sequencia = sequencia + f'{i} '

        i = i + 1
    else:
         sequencia = sequencia[:-1] + '\n'


print(sequencia[:-1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente o que faz seu código demorar é a criação e concatenação de várias strings (sem contar os *slices* como `[:-1]`, que também geram outra string).

Uma forma mais eficiente é usar [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (entenda os motivos [lendo aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153322/112052)), juntamente com um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), que já gera a sequência de números:

```
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0: break
    print(' '.join(map(str, range(1, n + 1))))
```

Lembrando que em um `range` o valor final não é incluso, por isso tem que colocar `n + 1`. E é preciso converter os números para string (usando `map` e `str`), caso contrário o `join` dá erro.

Outra vantagem é que você não precisa se preocupar com o espaço a mais no final, pois o `join` já cuida disso também.

Acabei de submeter e a solução foi aceita.