# Função que retorna as consoantes maiúsculas

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

a função  recebe como entrada uma frase e retorne a frase com todas as suas consoantes em maiúsculas.

```
def teste(frase):
    i=0
    while i<len(frase):
        if frase[i]in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxwyz':
            str.upper(frase[i])
        i=i+1
    return frase
```

Estou tentando com esse código mas ao invés de retornar só as consoantes maiúsculas, retorna a frase normal. obs: precisa ser usando o while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que [`upper` retorna **outra** string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper). Ele não altera a original (aliás, isso vale para todos os métodos que "modificam" a string - em Python, strings são imutáveis, e estes métodos na verdade sempre retornam outra string modificada).

Sendo assim, você tem que pegar o retorno e ir acumulando em outra string:

```
def consoantes_maiusculas(frase):
    s = ''
    for caractere in frase:
        if caractere in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxwyz':
            s += caractere.upper() # transforma em maiúscula
        else: # não é consoante minúscula, mantém como no original
            s += caractere
    return s

print(consoantes_maiusculas('abcdef')) # aBCDeF
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) juntamente com uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
def consoantes_maiusculas(frase):
    return ''.join(caractere.upper() if caractere in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxwyz' else caractere for caractere in frase)
```

Inclusive, usar `join` é o mais recomendado neste caso, [por ser bem mais eficiente do que a primeira alternativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153322/112052).

Comment: Valeu!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @João Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema

Comment: @hkotsubo, muita calma nessa hora, eu também estou no páreo :D

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa pode ser o uso do método [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) que retorna uma cópia da string na qual cada caractere foi mapeado através da tabela de tradução. Essa tabela de tradução pode ser construída com o método [`static str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) cujo a finalidade é retorna uma tabela de tradução usável para `str.translate()`. O método `static str.maketrans()` pode ser invocada com de um a três argumentos porém nesse caso específico o que interessa é a chamada com dois argumentos que devem ser strings de igual comprimento onde cada caractere no primeiro argumento será mapeado para o caractere na mesma posição no segundo argumento.

Uma consideração que deve ser feita sobre essa conversão é o caso especial da letra *C* pois ela possui uma variação o *Ç*.

Exemlplo:

```
def consoantes_maiusculas(frase):
    lowercase = 'bcçdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'         #Mapa de consoantes minúsculos com 'ç'.
    uppercase = 'BCÇDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'         #Mapa de consoantes maiúsculas com 'Ç'.
    tabela = str.maketrans(lowercase, uppercase) #Cria a tabela de tradução de caracteres.
    return frase.translate(tabela)               #Retorna a frase com os caracteres convertidos.
```

Uso:

```
>>>texto = 'Função que receba como entrada UMA frase e retorne a frase com todas as suas consoantes em maiúsculas'

>>>print(consoantes_maiusculas(texto)) 
FuNÇão Que ReCeBa CoMo eNTRaDa UMA FRaSe e ReToRNe a FRaSe CoM ToDaS aS SuaS CoNSoaNTeS eM MaiúSCuLaS
```