# Análise assintótica do melhor e pior caso

Tags: c#, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Quero saber qual seria o melhor e pior caso do meu código. Ainda não entendo muito bem como fazer esses tipos de análise em um código e queria ter alguma ajuda para saber como identificar. Eu entendo que é necessário saber seu tipo de complexidade e tudo mais, na teoria eu até entendo, mas na hora de analisar e colocar na prática fico sem rumo.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s, revs = "";
        Console.WriteLine(" Digite a Palavra");
        s = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            revs += s[i].ToString();
        }
        if (revs == s) 
        {
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Eu sempre falo que achar a complexidade real não é tão simples assim. Olhando por cima podemos dizer fácil que é O(n) sendo `n` o tamanho da *string* `s` que será sabida ao digitar o texto, ou seja, é complexidade linear, porque ele leva a quantidade de passos para executar igual ao tamanho de `s`.

Porém tem um problema que muita gente deixaria escapar. Quando você fica concatenando *string*, que é imutável por padrão no C#, há um custo adicional para copiar a *string* atual para uma nova, então em cada passo ainda existirá um custo de cópia acumulativo. Então se mudar o algoritmo e usar um objeto de *string* mutável devidamente inicializado pode só considerar o O(n). Pode ler mais em [O que faz o join() ser tão superior se comparado a outras técnicas de concatenação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153322/101).

E por outras razões é mais eficiente fazer:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine(" Digite a Palavra");
        var s = ReadLine();
        var revs = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
        for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) revs.Append(s.Substring(i, 1));
        WriteLine(revs);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kOmFkS). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cx5EbC). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Reverse.cs).

Mas se está tentando verificar um palíndromo tem maneira mais eficiente ainda, já que não precisa fazer cópia alguma e pode verificar só metade dos caracteres.

Pode ler mais em [O que é a complexidade de um algoritmo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33330/101).

Comment: Levando em consideração seu código que também tem sua complexidade O(n), como consigo identificar o melhor e pior caso? Seria algo parecido com uma função f(n)=5n para o melhor caso e para o pior f(n)=5ns. N sendo o tamanho da string e S para o numero de palavras digitadas?

Comment: Não existe número de palavras digitas, só existe o tamanho da *string*, que é o melhor e o pior caso, é muito simples. Eu nem sei como dizer para identificar porque qualquer cosia que percorra todos elementos é uma complexidade linear, e o código mostra justamente percorrendo toda coleção de dados.