# Por que objetos String são imutáveis?

Tags: java, string, orientação-a-objetos

Até a versão estável mais recente, Java 8, os objetos do tipo `String` são imutáveis. Ou seja, qualquer mudança em uma `String` causa a criação de um novo objeto `String`.

Isso não é prejudicial do ponto de vista de desempenho?

Qual foi a motivação para objetos `String` serem imutáveis? Ou, em uma linha mais geral, qual a principal intenção em fazer um objeto imutável?

Comment: Há boas respostas no SOen, dee uma olhada http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397861/why-is-string-immutable-in-java

Comment: Graças a String ser imutável, a JVM pode manter uma única instância de uma determinada String e compartilhá-la com outros lugares que utilizem este mesmo valor. Isto pode resultar em uma economia de memória.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isso nunca mudará, muito código foi feito com essa premissa. Poderia um dia ter algo adicional, de certa forma já tem que é o `StringBuilder`.

De uma maneira geral não é prejudicial na performance de forma que valha a pena ser diferente. Java, como algumas outras linguagens, não tem como objetivo ter a melhor performance possível e sim a performance mais adequada para a maioria das situações. Certamente perde em algumas coisas e ganha em outras.

## Concorrência

Um motivo para ser assim é a concorrência. É muito difícil lidar com objetos mutáveis quando o acesso pode ser feito em *threads* diferentes. Hoje isso é muito importante. Tratar o acesso à *string* mutável de forma concorrente é ruim do ponto de vista de performance porque exige travamento. Isso por si só já tem um custo. E pior, esse custo pode ser pago mesmo que não esteja fazendo nada concorrente. Ele é feito "por via das dúvidas". Até tem como otimizar isso, mas é bem complicado.

#### Proteção

Imagine que você recebe um nome de arquivo para abrir, aí o nome do arquivo é mudado por outra *thread* e aí a operação que era válida não é mais. Qual a solução? Teria que travar a *string* durante toda a operação. Só que aí pode ser que outras partes do código que precisem manipular essa *string* não conseguem mais fazer nada, tem que ficar esperando. Pode liberar logo, ou demorar horas, dias, É inviável. Qual a solução? Copiar o conteúdo, assim você tem um novo objeto. Mas pode ser que copiou algo que nem será alterado por outra *thread*. Então a cópia feita foi um **desperdício**. Na maior parte dos casos é isso que ocorre.

*Strings* mutáveis jogam a responsabilidade de proteger o texto para quem for ler. Na maior parte das vezes essa proteção não é necessária, mas você paga o preço assim mesmo, porque não tem como saber quando será necessária ou não, a não ser em código extremamente simples, o que não é o caso das bibliotecas da linguagem. Essas cópias nunca sabem se pode ocorrer algum problema de concorrência ou não.

#### Proteção no lugar correto

*Strings* imutáveis colocam o custo de proteger o texto para quem for mudar seu valor. Escritas ocorrem bem pouco em um código. É melhor pagar esse preço.

Se sabe que tem um caso que fará várias alterações [use o `StringBuilder`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101) e depois converta para `String` ([relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16050/101)). Essa é uma *string* mutável e não foi feita para uso indiscriminado, deve ser usada em um ponto específico e jamais compartilhada entre *threads*.

## Hashing

Dificulta ou até inviabiliza seu uso como chaves de estruturas como [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Se o código *hash* da *string* muda fácil, precisa reorganizar os *buckets* da estrutura a todo momento.

## Outros motivos

- *Strings* mutáveis são mais inseguras (acesso indevido)
- Dificultam o cache
- E o reaproveitamento ([*interning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) por [Flyweight](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164960/101))
- Além de otimizações em tempo de compilação
- Reflexão fica bem mais complicada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: big win!!!!!!!!