# Em Python, qual é a diferença entre == e o comando is?

Tags: python, comparação

Estou confuso no uso de dois comandos, o `is` e o `==` que até onde eu entendi realizam a mesma coisa que é comparar se dois objetos são iguais.

Existe algum mais performático?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Não, isso não é verdade.

O operador `==` testa igualdade de valores. Ele testa se os valores de objetos se equivalem.

O operador `is` testa a identidade dos objetos, então precisa ser o mesmo objeto para ele ser verdadeiro. Obviamente que se for o mesmo objeto eles se equivalerão em valor. Você não encontrará uma situação onde o `is` retorna `True` e o `==` retorna `False`.

Analise a diferença nesses códigos:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a #copia a referência para o objeto
print(b is a) #é o mesmo objeto
print(b == a) #ele possuem o mesmo valor
b = a[:] #copiou o objeto
print(b is a) #são objetos diferentes
print(b == a) #mas os valores são os mesmos
print(1000 is 10**3) #são objetos diferentes
print(1000 == 10**3) #mas o valor é o mesmo
print("a" + "b" + "c" is "abc") #objetos diferentes
print("a" + "b" + "c" == "abc") #valores iguais
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/sUnHnK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jnrwdttt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/EqualVsIs.py).

Você pode estar pensando o que ocorreu no último exemplo de *string* em que algo que parece ser outro objeto, mas é o mesmo. Há uma otimização que a concatenação é transforma em *string* simples. Mas ainda assim deveriam ser objetos diferentes. Mas uma uma coisa chamada [*interning*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164729/101) para economizar memória e se a linguagem puder detectar que é o mesmo valor, ele aponta para o mesmo objeto. Isso funciona bem quando *strings* são imutáveis, caso do Python.

Comment: (Ha casos do == ser falso, com o  `is` sendo True sim - embora sejam exceção,e em geral não sejam úteis - veja abaixo)

Comment: @jsbueno de fato, tem esse corner case :) Não vou mudar a resposta porque acho que para o caso adequado está correto, fica a ressalva que algum maluco realmente pode fazer isso acontecer.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 9):

Para complementar a resposta do Maniero - o `is` só compara se os objetos são o mesmo. O `==` compara se são iguais. Muita gente cai na armadilha de usar `is` para comparar strings - mas as vezes, por conta de otimizações internas do Python, calha das strings *serem* o mesmo objeto numa ocasião - e em outra (*string* maiores, lidas de arquivo, etc...), serem objetos distintos.

Então, mesmo que no *prompt* interativo o `is` volte `True`  para duas strings iguais, nunca use isso ao programar. O mesmo vale para números inteiros.
Em particular, o Python cria automaticamente uma instância de cada número de  0 a 255 ao se iniciar - e a comparação com `is` desses números sempre retorna `True` -  mas de novo, isso é só um detalhe de implementação.

Agora - em termos práticos, quando você define uma classe, você pode determinar o comportamento do `==`. Por padrão, para qualquer classe nova, a comparação `==` só retorna verdadeira se você está tratando do mesmo objeto:

```
In [13]: class A:
    ...:     pass
    ...: 

In [14]: a = b = A()

In [15]: a == b
Out[15]: True

In [16]: c = A()

In [17]: a == c
Out[17]: False
```

Mas se sua classe definir o método especial `__eq__`, ele recebe como parâmetros o próprio objeto (`self`) e o objeto com o qual está sendo comparado - nesse caso,  você determina a igualdade para seus próprios objetos. (Já o comportamento de `is` não pode ser personalizado).

```
In [18]: class B:
    ...:     value = 0  # Atributo de classe
    ...:     def __eq__(self, other):
    ...:         if hasattr(other, "value"):
    ...:             return self.value == other.value
    ...:         return self.value == other
    ...:     

In [19]: d = B()

In [20]: e = B()

In [21]: d == e
Out[21]: True

In [22]: e.value = 5  # sobrescreve value com um atributo para esta instância

In [23]: d == e
Out[23]: False
```

É até possível situações em que o `is` retorna `True` e o `==` False sim - basta que o método `__eq__` retorne False.  Em geral não tem muita utilidade, mas é usado pelo valor especial de ponto flutuante `Nan` (Not a number)

```
In [24]: a = float("Nan")

In [25]: b = a

In [26]: b is a
Out[26]: True

In [27]: b == a
Out[27]: False

In [28]: a == a
Out[28]: False
```