# Qual o operador equivalente a diferente em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Conheço alguns outros operadores:

- Maior que: `>`
- Menor que: `<`
- Igualdade: `==`

Mas e o operador "diferente", como é em Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11060508/4312593

Comment: Consegui resolver, Obrigado!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo apenas nas versões 2+, mas foi removido nas versões 3+

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, bom saber!! Atualizei-me

Answer (score 23):

Assim como na maioria das linguagens, o operador de diferença no Python é o `!=`. Vale lembrar que ele compara apenas o valor entre os operandos e não suas identidades.

```
a = 2
b = 3

if a != b:
    print('a é diferente de b')
else:
    print('a é igual a b')
```

Já adiantando, o operador `!=` invoca implicitamente o método `__ne__` do primeiro operando, passando o segundo como parâmetro, então se precisar sobrescrever tal operador em uma classe, é possível fazer:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.value != other.value

f1 = Foo(1)
f2 = Foo(1)

print(f1 != f2)  # False
```

Sem a sobrecarga do método, o resultado seria `True`, indicando que os objetos são diferentes, mesmo parecendo serem iguais.

---

O operador `is` (ou `is not`) verifica a identidade dos objetos e não somente seus valores. Isso fica evidente, por enquanto, quando trabalhado com tipos mutáveis:

```
a = [1]
b = [1]

print(a != b)  # False
print(a is not b)  # True
```

As listas `a` e `b` possuem o mesmo valor, mas não são o mesmo objeto.

**Leituras adicionais**

- [Em Python, quais as consequências em usar 'is' no lugar de '=='](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38104/5878)
- [Em Python, qual é a diferença entre == e o comando is?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174041/5878)

---

Outros operadores existentes na linguagem são:

- Adição, `a + b`, quando `a` e `b` são numéricos;

  ```
  >>> 1 + 2
  3
  ```
- Concatenação, `a + b`, quando `a` e `b` são sequências;

  ```
  >>> 'Anderson' + ' ' + 'Woss'
  'Anderson Woss'
  >>> [1, 2] + [3, 4]
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
  ```
- Contenção, `a in b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 in [1, 2, 3, 4]
  True
  ```
- Divisão verdadeira, `a / b`, que retorna o resultado real;

  ```
  >>> 5/2
  2.5
  ```
- Divisão com truncamento, `a // b`, que retorna apenas a parte inteira;

  ```
  >>> 5//2
  2
  ```
- E binário, `a & b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 & 3
  1
  ```
- OU exclusivo binário, `a ^ b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 ^ 2
  3
  ```
- Inversão binária, `~a`;

  ```
  >>> ~2
  -3
  ```
- OU binário, `a | b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 | 2
  3
  ```
- Exponenciação, `a**b`;

  ```
  >>> 2**10
  1024
  ```
- Identidade, `a is b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 is None
  False
  ```
- Identidade, `a is not b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 is not None
  True
  ```
- Indexação, `obj[k]`;

  ```
  >>> obj = [1, 2, 3]
  >>> obj[1]
  2
  ```
- Atribuição por índice, `obj[k] = v`;

  ```
  >>> obj = [1, 2, 3]
  >>> obj[2] = 4
  >>> obj
  [1, 2, 4]
  ```
- Exclusão por índice, `del obj[k]`;

  ```
  >>> obj = [1, 2, 3]
  >>> del obj[1]
  >>> obj
  [1, 3]
  ```
- Deslocamento binário para esquerda, `a << b`;

  ```
  >>> 4 << 1
  8
  ```
- Deslocamento binário para direita, `a >> b`;

  ```
  >>> 4 >> 1
  2
  ```
- Resto de divisão, `a % b`;

  ```
  >>> 5 % 2
  1
  ```
- Multiplicação, `a * b`;

  ```
  >>> 2 * 3
  6
  ```
- Multiplicação de matriz, `a @ b` (**versões 3.5+**);

  Ver [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/);
- Negação aritmética, `-a`;

  ```
  >>> -4
  -4
  ```
- Negação lógica, `not a`;

  ```
  >>> not True
  False
  ```
- Positivo, `+a`;

  ```
  >>> +4
  4
  ```
- Fatiamento, `seq[i:j]`;

  ```
  >>> obj = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  >>> obj[1:3]
  [2, 3]
  ```
- Atribuição por fatiamento, `seq[i:j] = values`;

  ```
  >>> obj = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  >>> obj[1:3] = [8, 9]
  >>> obj
  [1, 8, 9, 4, 5]
  ```
- Exclusão por fatiamento, `del seq[i:j]`;

  ```
  >>> obj = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  >>> del obj[1:3]
  >>> obj
  [1, 4, 5]
  ```
- Formatação de *string*, `s % obj` (prefira método [`format`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878) ou [*f-strings*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/264722/5878));

  ```
  >>> 'Olá, %s' % 'mundo'
  'Olá, mundo'
  ```
- Subtração, `a - b`;

  ```
  >>> 3 - 1
  2
  ```
- Teste de verdade, `if obj: ...`;

  ```
  >>> obj = 3
  >>> if obj: print('Ok')
  'Ok'
  ```
- Menor que, `a < b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 < 2
  True
  ```
- Menor ou igual a, `a <= b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 <= 2
  True
  ```
- Maior que, `a > b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 > 2
  False
  ```
- Maior ou igual a, `a >= b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 >= 2
  False
  ```
- Entre, não inclusivo, `a < v < b`;

  ```
  >>> v = 5
  >>> 1 < v < 9
  True
  ```
- Entre, inclusivo, `a <= v <= b`;

  ```
  >>> v = 5
  >>> 1 <= v <= 9
  True
  ```
- Igualdade, `a == b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 == 2
  False
  ```
- Diferença, `a != b`;

  ```
  >>> 1 != 2
  True
  ```
- Diferença, `a <> b` (obsoleto a partir da versão 2.5, removido nas versões 3+);

  ```
  >>> 1 <> 2
  True
  ```

Outras informações podem ser vistas na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html).

Answer (score -6):

No Python você poderia usar Diferente "!=", ou Não é "is not"

```
if "Foo" != "Bar":
    return "Diferente"

if "Foo" is not "Bar":
    return "Diferente"
```

Comment: `!=` e `is not` são coisas completamente diferentes.