# Mostre na tela a seguinte operação com a tupla Tu: (ab)+(bc)+(cd)+(de)/e

Tags: python

Mostre na tela a seguinte operação com a tupla Tu:

```
(ab)+(bc)+(cd)+(de)/e  
tu=(10,20,30,40,50)  
a,b,c,d,e=tu  



print(ab)+(bc)+(cd)+(de)/e

  NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)  
  <ipython-input-28-342d00e3a09e> in <module>()  
  ----> 1 print(ab)+(bc)+(cd)+(de)/e  

NameError: name 'ab' is not defined
```

Pessoal, como eu faço a soma de tuplas em parenteses? Sou iniciante na   programação

Comment: Para formatar o código, selecione ele por completo e aperte o atalho `CTRL+K`

Comment: `ab` deverá ser os valores consternados ou multiplicados?

Comment: Em "consternados", leia-se concatenados.

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias ambiguidades na pergunta que afetam diretamente a solução.

A primeira é que não temos como saber, com certeza, se o valor `ab` deve ser a concatenação dos valores `a` e `b`, ficando 1020, ou se `ab` deve ser o produto entre `a` e `b`, ficando 200. Qualquer que seja a forma correta, seu código está errado.

- Se for concatenação, você precisa converter para *string* e utilizar o operador `+`: `str(a)+str(b)`; ou, no Python 3.6+ utilizar as *f-string*: `f'{a}{b}'`;
- Se for multiplicação, você precisa utilizar o operador `*`: `a*b`;

Falei um pouco dos operadores do Python em [Qual o operador equivalente a diferente em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309730/5878)

A segunda é que você colocou `(ab)+(bc)+(cd)+(de)/e`. Isso significa, matematicamente que apenas o valor `de` será dividido por `e`, o que resultaria apenas em `d`, se `e` for diferente de zero.

Como acredito que o correto seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você precisará colocar todo o seu denominador entre parenteses: `((ab)+(bc)+(cd)+(de))/e`.

Fazendo essas correções, provavelmente você chegará no resultado esperado.