# Pode ocorrer vazamento de memória em Java?

Tags: java, memória, garbage-collector, memory-leaks

Na linguagem C, por exemplo, os vazamentos de memória são comuns porque a responsabilidade de desalocar a memória fica sob responsabilidade do programador. No exemplo abaixo (retirado da Wikipedia) podemos verificar uma situação clássica de vazamento de memória.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

void funcao_que_aloca(void) {
    /* aloca um array de 45 floats */
    float *a = malloc(sizeof(float) * 45);

    /* volta pro main sem liberar memória */
}

int main(void) {
    funcao_que_aloca();

    /* o ponteiro 'a' não existe mais, mas a memória continua alocada*/
}
```

Uma vez que em Java temos o garbage collector e a responsabilidade de liberar a memória não fica com o programador, quão seguro é dizer que aplicações em Java são livres de vazamento de memória? Eles existem? Caso sim, há algum precaução específico para evitar o problema?

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 6):

## O que é vazamento de memória?

Primeiro precisamos definir o que é vazamento de memória.

Tecnicamente Java não pode ter vazamentos se considerar que o vazamento só ocorre quando algo é alocado e nunca ocorre a possibilidade de liberação quando não há mais referências para este objeto.

Se considerar que vazamento é toda memória ocupada sem que tenha uma referência para aquele objeto, então Java vaza memória o tempo todo. Só não terá memória vazada quando o GC rodar e limpar tudo o que não há mais referências. Logo em seguida ele começa vazar de novo. Se não considera isso um vazamento, ficamos ainda com a definição que Java nunca vaza memória.

Se considerar que vazamento é quando você tem um objeto referenciado ainda em algum lugar, mas esse objeto não será mais usado na aplicação, aí ocorre o vazamento e pode ser por diversas razões. Mas muita gente não considera isso vazamento já que o objeto está referenciado.

## Formas de vazamento

- Um objeto pode continuar sendo referenciado sem uso se ele estiver atrelado a uma variável estática direta ou indiretamente (explico abaixo). Mas se definiu que ele é estático provavelmente é o que deseja, não? Se não é, cometeu um erro, mas eu não chamaria de vazamento de memória, é uma engenharia errada.
- Se um objeto está atrelado a uma instância e essa instância por alguma razão nunca morre, então a referência a ele nunca morre também. Há quem diga que é vazamento de memória, eu continuo achando que é erro de engenharia, se não for uma necessidade real, e se for uma necessidade, então está tudo ok.
- Se você tem um método em uma *thread* rodando em paralelo e ela fica executando o tempo todo, e nesse método tem uma variável local que referencia um objeto que não é usado mais depois de alguma operação. Seria um vazamento de memória?

  Na verdade com *threads* tem muita situação que é fácil manter referências mais tempo do que se deseja.
- Quando faz [*interning* de *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164729/101) é como ter um objeto estático.
- Quando abre algum recurso e não fecha, o objeto é alocado em memória não gerenciada e fica lá sem coleta. Por isso se recomenda abrir sempre com [`try-resource`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172909/101). Isso seria claramente um vazamento, mas o GC pode dar conta disso se não houver referências.
- Quando se faz um *pool* de objetos você pode estar segurando outros objetos referenciados ali. Ou seja, um objeto no *pool* não está em uso mais, mas ele está vivo, e tudo o que está atrelado a ele e também não serve para mais nada continua vivo. Talvez possa ser considerado vazamento de memória, mas ainda acho que é erro de engenharia, ou comportamento normal do mecanismo.
- Algo semelhante pode ocorrer com *cache*, mas é mais raro. Cache feito corretamente possui referências fracas, portanto a sua liberação pode ocorrer facilmente.
- Se usar [`sun.misc.Unsafe`](http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/) você pode ter um vazamento, afinal ele permite acessar a memória de forma não gerenciada.
- Tem uma lista de algoritmos que segura uma referência onde não deve, mas não vai querer que liste vários exemplos aqui, né?

  Em geral isso ocorre quando se pega um elemento de um *array* ou de uma classe e acha que está copiando ele, quando na verdade está referenciando o elemento. Então você pode não ter mais nenhuma referência para a ponta do *array* enorme, mas ainda tem uma referência para um elemento dele. O *array* não pode ser liberado. Tecnicamente isto não é vazamento de memória, mas o efeito é muito semelhante. O certo aí é copiar o conteúdo da referência.

  Isso vale para qualquer tipo de *array*, incluindo `String`. Um simples e aparentemente inofensivo `substring()` pode segurar uma referência mais tempo do que deseja. Você carrega um livro, faz um `substring()` em uma palavra e pronto, o livro não pode mais ser liberado até a variável que segura essa palavra for liberada, mesmo que nada mais referencie o livro (parece que isso não ocorre mais em versões recentes, mas se criou outros problemas novos).

  Em Java isso ocorre mais porque quase tudo é referência (isso começará mudar em Java 10).
- O que é consumido pela própria JVM e não é liberado, pode ser considerado vazamento de memória?

Nem vou falar daqueles *corner cases* que podem ocorrer de um jeito muito forçado, praticamente explorando um brecha que é até difícil reproduzir.

## Como resolver

Há casos em que você precisa anular manualmente uma variável para liberar a referência, mas eu costumo dizer que se fez isso provavelmente tem algo errado no código. Pode existir alguma razão para fazê-lo, mas quase sempre é gambiarra.

No geral é precisa conhecer bem a linguagem, as bibliotecas que está usando e ficar atento ao que está fazendo. Ao contrário do que muita gente pena, O GC não elimina a necessidade de pensarmos no gerenciamento da memória.

Liberar memória não é sua preocupação, liberar referências continua sendo sua responsabilidade. Não vai sair dando `null` em todo canto.

Diminuir a quantidade de alocações ainda é interessante para ter uma aplicação mais eficiente e Java finalmente começou tomar esse caminho.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

Pode sim ocorrer, mesmo com a existência do Garbage Collector (GC). Normalmente, os vazamentos de memória em Java ocorrerão por erros de programação.

Por exemplo, um exemplo simples que gera vazamento de memória:

```
public Object pop() {
if (size == 0)
    throw new EmptyStackException();
return elements[--size];
```

}

O código acima efetua a remoção de um elemento da pilha. Por exemplo, se o você usar o método pop() em elements[5], terá como resultado o elements[4]. Porém, os objetos removidos da pilha não serão coletados pelo GC. Restarão referências obsoletas do elements[5] mesmo após o pop() que serão ignoradas pelo GC e todas as referências existentes ligadas ao objeto citado também continuarão à existir, atrapalhando consideravelmente o desempenho de sua aplicação.

Uma correção para o método citado acima, seria anular as referências quando elas se tornarem obsoletas, como segue no exemplo abaixo:

```
public Object pop() {
if (size == 0)
    throw new EmptyStackException();

Object result = elements[--size];
elements[size] = null;
return result;
}
```

A seguir, um artigo do [Devmedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/eliminando-vazamentos-de-memoria-em-java/28349), que contem o exemplo citado acima e responde sua pergunta de forma mais completa.

Comment: Não desqualificando sua resposta, mas seria interessante transcrever brevemente a explicação do link aqui, para que, caso ele venha a sair do ar, a resposta não fique invalida.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica diegofm. Trouxe um exemplo simples e uma breve explicação do artigo citado para não ocorrer o que você citou.