# Em quais casos retornam o erro do tipo System.OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net, exceção

Quais são os casos mais frequentes que podem retornar essa *exception*?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como identificar e evitar memory leak no .NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186644/como-identificar-e-evitar-memory-leak-no-net)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basicamente é falta de memória. Ocorre mais em máquinas 32 bits que pode ter aplicações de no máximo 2GB no total, em 64 bits é menos comum mas também tem limite, e costuma ficar bem lento antes de acontecer isto.

Pode ser falta geral de memória ou pode ser que um objeto está grande demais. Geralmente objetos não podem ter mais que 2GB, salvo [configuração especial em 64 bits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225692/101).

Outros problemas do gerenciador de memória podem causar algo assim.

Acontece que muitas vezes isto corre por erro do programador. Não é que ele está carregando muitos objetos e grandes na memória, é que ele não está liberando-os.

Muita gente acha que pelo fato do .NET ter um coletor de lixo pode fazer qualquer bagunça e tudo fica bem. Não é bem assim. Não pode prender memória sem querer. A memória só é liberada quando o .NET sabe que não há referências para aquela porção de memória e não é um recurso não gerenciado. Se fizer isto há uma [vazamento de memória](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/179599/101) (é Java, mas é quase igual).

Se está usando uma classe com a interface [`Disposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e não está fechando o recurso, provavelmente com `using` terá vazamento.

Se está usando um evento e não libera a lista de assinaturas quando o objeto não é mais necessário, terá vazamento.

Se coloca em uma área estática ou algo com tempo de vida próximo ao do tempo de vida da aplicação então há uma referência para algo que talvez não precise mais e tem um vazamento. Isto pode valer para algoritmos mal pensados.

Tem uma série de casos descritos no *link* acima que causam também, mas estes são mais comuns.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Complementando, só por curiosidade... Tem muitos casos em que você precisa tratar uma informação bem definida sequencial (por exemplo, ler a resposta de um webservice ou ler um grande arquivo texto). Porém, a resposta fornecida pode ser grande demais. No lugar de carregar tudo em memória para depois processar, você pode fazer o processamento parcial do que foi lido e descartar conforme não precisa mais da informação.