# O que é .= em php?

Tags: php, string, operadores

O que é `.=` em PHP? Estou com dúvida se é uma concatenação ou multiplicação.

Comment: Veja aqui: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: Obrigado! Falha minha.

Comment: Melhor ainda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202331/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-php

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.=` é uma forma mais enxuta de concatenar sem precisar reescrever a a variável:

Seria similar a isso: `$variavel = $variavel . "sua string concatenada";`

Nesta situação, você está dizendo que a variável receberá algo novo que irá concatenar com o que ela já possui.

Ou seja:

```
$variavel = "texto";

$variavel .=" novo";

echo $variavel;
```

A saída da `$variavel` será: `"texto novo"`

Essa regra também se aplica para cálculos:

- `+=` (soma) => Exemplo: `$soma = 2; $soma+=2;`a saída de `$soma` será **4**;
- `-=` (subtração)
- `/=` (divisão)
- `*=` (multiplicação)

**Dica:** Conheço duas maneiras de fazer concatenações em fila, uma delas é esta:

```
$variavel = "letras: A,";
$variavel .= "B,";
$variavel .= "C";
```

Outra é utilizando array:

```
$variavel = [];
$variavel[] = "letras: A";
$variavel[] = "B";
$variavel[] = "C";

echo implode(",", $variavel);
```

Answer (score 12):

Serve para concatenar *strings*. Ele vai adicionando um novo texto a um texto já existe na variável.

```
$texto .= "um texto aqui";
```

é o mesmo que

```
$texto = $texto . "um texto aqui".
```

Outro exemplo:

```
$texto = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $texto .= $i . " ";
}
echo $texto;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/XVvVoC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dwvapbqp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Concatenation3.php).

Achei uma [resposta no SO com uma curiosidade sobre performance do uso de concatenação e construção de *string* com classes especializada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16112845/221800). No PHP a concatenação é muito barata porque a *string* é mutável. No C#, por ser imutável, ela [custa caro se fizer em grande proporção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90467/101), então o [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) vai muito melhor quando precisa desse padrão em grande quantidade. Mas note que usando certo, em C# a performance é bem melhor, como era de se esperar.

A multiplicação seria

```
$valor *= 2;
```

Se isso estiver em um laço, ele vai dobrando o valor cada passagem do laço.

Answer (score 9):

É o mesmo que `+=` em outras linguagens. Como PHP não é tipado, `.=` é usado para `strings`, ele adiciona o texto à direita ao texto já existente na `string`.

```php
$texto = "Hello, ";
$texto .= "World";
echo($texto); 

//Saída > Hello, World
```

[Leia sobre as operações em string na documentação do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 4):

Eu diria que `.=` é uma forma de contração (um encurtamento) para a sintaxe de concatenação, a fim de torná-la mais simples.

Em PHP, o operador de `.` é responsável pela concatenação de `strings`.

Exemplo:

```
$ab = 'a' . 'b'

var_dump($ab); // ab
```

Porém, o operador `.=` vai fazer uma concatenação de uma `string` combinando-a com o valor já existente na variável.

```
$ab = 'a';

$ab .= 'b';

var_dump($ab); // 'ab'
```

Assim, utilizar o operador `.=` torna, em alguns casos, a operação mais fácil do que se fosse utilizando o `.`.

Exemplo:

```
$texto = "o rato roeu"

$texto .= " a roupa do rei de Roma"
```

Se você fosse utilizar o operador `.`, seu código ficaria um pouco maior:

```
$texto = "o rato roeu"

$texto = $texto . " a roupa do rei de Roma"
```