# Quando usar String e StringBuilder

Tags: c#, string, concatenação-de-string, stringbuilder

Existe uma outra perguna sobre
[Qual o meio mais apropriado para se concatenar strings?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124/qual-o-meio-mais-apropriado-para-se-concatenar-strings). Nela explica os possíveis tipos de concatenações no `C#`.

Mas, quando devemos usar `System.String` e quando devemos usar `System.Text.StringBuilder`? Qual a diferença entre os dois? E, o melhor, quando **não** utilizar?

Comment: Não entendo que seja a mesma pergunta. Na referenciada, pergunta-se os tipos de concatenção, aqui pergunto quando se deve usar concatenação e quando usar StringBuilder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiramente vamos conhecer os dois tipos.

## [System.String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.aspx)

O tipo `string` é um [tipo de referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/string) dentro do .NET Framework. Portante ele "vive" apenas na memória *heap*, uma memória de armazenamento de objetos simples e de acesso rápido.

Mas sua principal característica é o tipo `string` é um [objeto imutável](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_imut%C3%A1vel), ou seja, quando definimos um novo valor à um tipo `string`, o que ocorre é que o valor antigo é completamente destruído, e em uma nova posição de memória é armazenado o novo valor, então o objeto `string` passa a fazer referência à essa nova posição na memória.

Veja na imagem abaixo como é esse comportamento.

[image: Fonte: PASIONATE TALKS]
Fonte: https://passionatetalks.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/why-strings-are-immutable-in-dot-net/

Essa "recriação" da *string* a cada concatenação é, de certa forma, custosa

## [System.Text.StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netstandard-2.0)

O tipo `StringBuilder`, já é um tipo complexo, representa um tipo mutável de cadeia de caracteres, ou seja, um tipo mutável de `string`.

Ele funciona da seguinte maneira: A cada vez que uma nova `string` é adicionada, ele quebra essa `string` em `char`s e armazena um a um em um `char[]` interno. [Veja seu código fonte aqui](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs#L554).

A vantagem disse é que ele garante que um valor jamais será "recriado", como acontece com o tipo `string`. Cada vez que um novo valor é adicionar, ele apenas inserido na sua pilha.

Isso, claro, vem com outras vantagens. Com `StringBuilder` é possível remover um único `char` do meio da cadeia, assim como também é possível inserir um `char` no meio da cadeia. Ambos apenas especificando a posição por índice.

## Quando utilizar cada um?

> Se o StringBuilder é mais performático que o `string`, então sempre devo usar `StringBuilder` para concatenação?

Claro que não. Deve-se utilizar quando realmente valer a pena. Importante não esquecer que o `StringBuilder` é um tipo complexo, deve ser instanciado. Poranto é mais custoso para ser inicializado.

No caso de uma concatenação simples como o exemplo abaixo, não valeria a pena usar `StringBuilder`:

```
var nome = "Thiago";
var sobrenome "Lunardi";
var nomeCompleto = nome +" "+ sobrenome;
nomeCompleto;
> "Thiago Lunardi"
```

Pois é uma execução curta - apenas uma concatenação - tornando, nesse caso, apenas o uso do tipo `string` mais eficiente.

Mas, já no caso abaixo, valeria a pena uma refatoração:

```
var nomesDosAlunos = string.Empty;
foreach(var aluno in salaDeAula.Alunos)
    nomesDosAlunos += aluno.Nome + ',';
```

Afinal, nesse caso, a cada loop, uma nova `string` é reconstruída. Esse seria uma boa oportunidade de ganho de performance com `StringBuilder`.

```
var nomesDosAlunos = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var aluno in salaDeAula.Alunos)
    nomesDosAlunos.Append(aluno.Nome).Append(',');
```

### Há como melhorar ainda mais?

Sim, há, não muito mais, mas dependendo do cenário, a melhora é significativa.

No `StringBuilder`, a cada vez que um novo valor é adicionado, ele precisa [expandir sua capacidade de armazenamento](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs#L1962). Isso requer, mesmo que mínimo, um tempo de processamento para alocação do novo bloco.

Para agilizar, pode-se inicializar o `StringBuilder` já com o tamanho esperado, assim, ao adicionar novo valores, não consumirá tempo expandindo seus blocos.

```
var nomesDosAlunos = new StringBuilder(salaDeAula.Alunos.Count);
foreach(var aluno in salaDeAula.Alunos)
    nomesDosAlunos.Append(aluno.Nome).Append(',');
```

## Teste de Performance

Escrevi um script no .NET Fiddle para fazer um [teste de performance String vs StringBuilder](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B4UcTp).

```
public class Program
{
    private static Stopwatch _watch = new Stopwatch();
    public static void Main()
    {
        for(var times = 1; times <= 1000; times *= 10)
        {
            var stringTestResult = Test(() => StringTest(times));
            var stringBuilderTestResult = Test(() => StringBuilderTest(times));
            var stringBuilderPresetTestResult = Test(() => StringBuilderPresetTest(times));

            if(times < 1) {times=1;continue;} // first time is warming up, doesn't count
            Console.WriteLine($"Testing against {times} times concatenation.");
            Console.WriteLine($"String: {stringTestResult}");
            Console.WriteLine($"StringBuilder: {stringBuilderTestResult}");
            Console.WriteLine($"StringBuilderPreset: {stringBuilderPresetTestResult}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public static long Test(Action test)
    {
        _watch.Restart();
        for(var x =0; x<=100; x++) test();
        _watch.Stop();
        var ticks = _watch.ElapsedTicks;        
        return ticks;
    }

    public static void StringTest(int times)
    {
        var s = string.Empty;           
        for(var x = 0; x < times; x++)
            s += ' ';
    }

    public static void StringBuilderTest(int times)
    {
        var s = new StringBuilder();
        for(var x = 0; x < times; x++)
            s.Append(' ');
    }

    public static void StringBuilderPresetTest(int times)
    {
        var s = new StringBuilder(times);
        for(var x = 0; x < times; x++)
            s.Append(' ');
    }
}
```

A ideia é, para os tipos `string` e `StringBuilder`, concatenar diversas vezes um `char` e mensurar quantos [ticks](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.ticks?view=netstandard-2.0#System_DateTimeOffset_Ticks) foram necessário para cada operação.

Um dos resultados foi o seguinte:

```
Testing against 1 times concatenation.
String: 17
StringBuilder: 33
StringBuilderPreset: 11

Testing against 10 times concatenation.
String: 37
StringBuilder: 29
StringBuilderPreset: 15

Testing against 100 times concatenation.
String: 584
StringBuilder: 80
StringBuilderPreset: 56

Testing against 1000 times concatenation.
String: 89935
StringBuilder: 658
StringBuilderPreset: 425
```

Percebam que, concatenando poucas vezes, o `string` é mais rapido que o `StringBuilder`, porem, com o aumento do número de concatenações, o `StringBuilder` passa a ser bem mais performático.

Comment: Você disse que string é um tipo primitivo, mas se eu uso o código: `typeof(string).IsPrimitive` ele me retorna um false, sabe explicar o motivo?

Comment: @GabrielColetta não foi eu quem disse, por isso pus o link com a [lista de tipos primitivos](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/framework-libraries#primitive-types) para citar a fonte. Realmente fiquei curioso. Vou pesquiar e adiciono aqui o que encontrar.

Comment: @GabrielColetta realmente existe uma bela discussão sobre isso. No fim, encontrei algo mais dentro do contexto. Para o .NET, `string` é um Tipo de Valor, e não um Tipo de Referência. E essa distinção satisfaz para o contexto do conteúdo. Inclusive atualizei os links. Obrigado pelo apontameno.