# Concatenar string

Tags: c#

Quero concatenar o dia atual com o caractere "0", só que não estou conseguindo.

```
string diaAtual = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
string diaFormatado = diaAtual+"0";
```

Preciso fazer isso para inserir em um select que estou usando. Pois no banco de dados a data esta em um formato diferente. O dia 01 é 10, o dia 02 é 20 e assim por diante. Então estou usando o select a seguir para pegar as datas menores que hoje

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SALES_ORDER) AS SALES_ORDER, COUNT(DISTINCT DELIVERY) 
AS DELIVERY, COUNT(MATERIAL) AS MATERIAL 
FROM V_CABOS WHERE DT_INI IS NOT NULL AND DT_FIM IS NULL AND PRIORIDADE < 30
```

Só que no lugar do dia que quer dizer 3 (dia atual), quero colocar a concatenação que no caso seria diaFormatado.

Comment: O que aconteceu ao executar esse código?

Comment: O dia primeiro tem que ser 10, o dia 2 tem que ser 20 e assim por diante. Preciso fazer isso para colocar em um select e pegar tudo que for menor que a data atual, só que a data no banco esta da forma que expliquei a cima

Comment: Vale a pena ler [**esse post**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124/qual-o-meio-mais-apropriado-para-se-concatenar-strings)

Comment: Ok, mas deu algum erro no código? Explique melhor a parte de "não estou conseguindo", por favor

Comment: Esse é o select que estou usando: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SALES_ORDER) AS SALES_ORDER, COUNT(DISTINCT DELIVERY) AS DELIVERY, COUNT(MATERIAL) AS MATERIAL 
FROM V_CABOS WHERE DT_INI IS NOT NULL AND DT_FIM IS NULL AND PRIORIDADE < 30. O 30 quer dizer que é dia 3. Se eu executar o código com o valor 30, ele funciona normalmente. Só que ao tentar concatenar o dia atual com o 0 para que fique 30, o select só retorna 0.

Comment: Você tem certeza de que que você quer concatenar à direita? se está trabalhando com data, poderia adicionar 10 dias... se você quer preencher o espaço vazio em uma string, poderia utilizar os `PadRight()` mas ainda assim não faz sentido. O que exatamente você está fazendo e o que deseja com isso?

Comment: Como assim 30 quer dizer 3? 300 seria 30?

Comment: No banco de dados o dia 01 esta como 10, o dia 02 como 20, e assim por diante. Quero pegar tudo que for menor que o dia atual, que no caso é 30. Então para que eu não fique mudando o código todo dia, quero pegar apenas o dia atual sem o zero e adicionar o zero a direita. Sim 300 seria 30

Comment: Não está claro porque você precisa fazer isso, parecendo inclusive ser um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878). Quanto ao problema na pergunta, não entendo muito de C#, mas testei o seu código e concatenou os valores, o que deixa sua pergunta ainda mais confusa.

Comment: Mas o dia 1 é guardado como 10 ? E o 10 seria 100 ? Parece muito estranho o que está a tentar fazer. Qual o objetivo dessa transformação ? Porque motivo ficou armazenado dessa maneira no banco ?

Comment: Isso vem de um sistema usado onde trabalho. Ele formata a data desta forma no banco. Sim o dia 1 é 10 e o dia 10 é 100.

Answer (score 1):

para obter o dia atual já com duas casas você deve usar o comando:

```
string diaAtual = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
```

Comment: Não posso pegar a data dessa forma. Tenho que pegar a data do formato de 1 a 31 e não de 01 a 31.